# Updating date for all files in scratch directory periodically

Tags: linux, date

I am using a shared linux server that deletes files after 2 weeks. I would like to write a script that updates the date for all of my directories and files (basically, everything in my scratch directory) to the current date and set up my .bashrc to run the script everytime I login. However, I am pretty new to bash and python scripting so I'm not sure where to begin. I would appreciate any help, and please let me know if any other information is needed.

Thank you!

Comment: Stop using that service and use one of many (free, or not so free) hosting providers that doesn't delete your files. Suppose your fix doesn't fire for a couple of weeks. Can you afford to lose whatever data it is that you keep on this server?

Comment: Orthogonal to your question here, but if the server won't store your data reliably, you need a backup. Actually, you need a backup anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can do simply:

```
find scratch_dir -exec touch {} +
```

for running the most possible matches at one time or if your `find` implementation don't handle `+`:

```
find scratch_dir -exec touch {} \;
```

to do it for each match separately.

You can add it in `~/.profile` files that depends of your shell/distro.